# Match a value in RDD in Scala using Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

```
((Cool,Yes),3)
((Cool,No),1)
((Mild,Yes),4)
((Mild,No),2)
```

I have RDD like this. I want to extract RDD with yes as one ouput and number associated with yes or no as another output.
e.g. Output 1: 
`((Cool,Yes),3)
((Mild,Yes),4)` 
Output 2:
3 for `((Cool,Yes),3)`.

Can anyone please tell me how to do this in Scala?

What I have tried:

```
def check(s : Array[((String, String), Int)]) : Boolean = 
  if (prob2.equals("Yes")) true else false 

val res = inFile.map{ x => check(prob2) }
```

Comment: `def check( s : Array[((String, String), Int)]) : Boolean = if (prob2.equals("Yes")) true else false
 val res = inFile.map{ x => check(prob2) }`  this I have tried this. Prob2 is what I am getting ((Cool,Yes),3)
((Cool,No),1)
((Mild,Yes),4)
((Mild,No),2)

Comment: Please edit your post and add your additional code there rather than in a comment.

Comment: RDDs with what look like weather measurements are quite common in StackOverflow questions, so I suspect this is an assignment from some course. Did you search Stackoverflow for other questions/answers on this topic?

Comment: True to that @TheArchetypalPaul! It feels like we are doing graduate homework nowadays. It's quite frustrating!

Comment: What do you mean by "extract the number for associated with every yes"? We can see in your example that the number you mean for row 1 is 3, but what is the overall result? Please edit your question and add the output you want.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul: I want all those numbers means for row1, 3 for row2, 1 and so on. I have checked other questions too but they are not matching with my requirement.

Comment: @eliasah: this is the sample dataset people usually work on and not some course.

Comment: So you don't care whether the row contains yes or no? Just want to extract the numbers? `rdd.map(_._2)` , then. If you want something more then please EDIT YOUR POST and add *exactly* what you want as output.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul: I have edited and mentioned exactly what I want as output. Kindly check

Comment: @Aditi please read what you have written again. _"I want to extract RDD with yes as one ouput and number associated with yes or no as another output. e.g. Output 1:  ((Cool,Yes),3)
((Mild,Yes),4) Output 2: 3 for ((Cool,Yes),3)"_ makes no sense

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt: why it doesn't make any sense? I have written what I want as an output

Comment: @Aditi, no, I don't think you have. Do you really want "Output 2: 3 for ((Cool,Yes),3)."?  Why is this just the row with value 3? Please slow down. and instead of trying to deal with the ambiguities with a short comment,  spend a few minutes carefully describing what your input is, and your desired output. it's the quickest way to get your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still having to guess a bit what you want, but assuming Output 1 is what you mean...

With a List, but RDD works the same:

```
val data = List((("Cool","Yes"),3),
                (("Cool","No"),1),
                (("Mild","Yes"),4),
                (("Mild","No"),2))

def check(row: ((String, String), Int), value:String) = row._1._2 == value

data.filter(check(_,"Yes"))
// List(((Cool,Yes),3), ((Mild,Yes),4))
data.filter(check(_,"No"))       
// List(((Cool,No),1), ((Mild,No),2))
```

Comment: This is what I am expecting. Let me try